# How can I make a method to take only serializable objects?

Tags: .net, serializable, type-safety, iserializable

Although there is an interface named [`ISerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable), it seems to purpose to customize details when a type is marked [`[Serializable]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute). If I understood correctly, the `[Serializable]` attribute by itself does not touch anything on a type it is attached to, but at run-time things implementing [`IFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iformatter) determine if a given object is marked `[Serializble]` attribute (through reflection? I guess). Also [`IFormatter.Serializble()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iformatter.serialize) method takes just any [`Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object). Does it mean virtually every object in .NET can be serialized? If not, is there way to take only serializable objects and make a compile-time error if a non-serializable object is passed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this for all types that might be serializable, except perhaps by writing a custom Roslyn analyzer that applies the exact rules you want, and adds the warnings that you want. This is a lot of work, and it may be simpler to simply add unit tests / integration tests that cover the serialization scenarios that you intend to support.

Additional notes:

- `[Serializable]` is a pseudo-attribute - it actually maps to an IL flag, not a regular attribute annotation, and additionally it is only used by some serializers (very much not all)
- the serializers that use the `ISerializable` / `IFormatter` APIs are generally the *last* serializers you want to use for most general purpose scenarios - they are typically much more brittle and type-bound that other more forgiving serializers (json, xml, protobuf etc)

> Does it mean virtually every object in .NET can be serialized?

No. However, different serializers have different rules for when things *can* be serialized, and those rules are often multiple and varied... i.e. it can look like X *or* like Y *or* like Z. As such, the only API that accepts all 3 is: `object`